# Simple Example of creating a PowerPoint file

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

I'm looking for some sample code on how to add an image and text & output it as a PowerPoint file.
The host server does not have Office and I'm not allowed to install anything so the "Manipulating Excel 2007 and PowerPoint 2007 Files with the Open XML Format API " will not help me. **Below is the code the output the PowerPoint. I just don't know of to add text and images.**

```
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename.ppt");
    Response.ContentType = "application/powerpoint";
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

Comment: Aron, just to clarify, you need to add the image/text *from* the server or can you do it client-side and add the edited file back to the server?

Answer (score 5):

If you cant use the Open XML Format API then a bad approach would be to create the whole package/XML/ZIP by code which I feel is a bad solution....

Good article how to create ppt using Open Xml API 
http://openxmldeveloper.org/articles/7429.aspx

Good luck

Comment: great article showing how to add slides + images to slides. Re-created the template file with openxml 2.5 productivity tool and creating a new visual studio project and dragged the sample code in order to get it to run.